# Can I find the position of B relative to A, seen from a different axis system?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, spherical-coordinates

I am not a mathematician in any sense of the word, so please bear with me.
I have the points A and B on the surface of a sphere (the two green points in the image).

Point A (with some additional data) is used as basis for a different axis system. This system's "custom" XYZ-axes are shown as black dotted lines marked with X1(inside), Y1 and Z1, however: *Origo is still at Origo* (so, in hindsight, this is a poor representation). To clarify, the point (0,0,0) is the same point regardless of system.

[image: Sphere]

A rectangular area around A is marked. This area is projected onto a 2D image, as if a map of an area on a planet surface, with A as center, Z1 as up and Y1 as right. I know the width and height of the area in radians.

I would like to find how far away B is in radians around both the Y1- and Z1-axes. To put it this way, if a point C was placed somewhere inside the marked rectangle, I would need to know how many radians "left/right" and how many radians "up/down" it's away to correctly place point C on the 2D map.

Visualized here:

[image]

Any ideas? Or is this completely crazy?

If relevant, each of the four corners of the rectangle are found by traversing `u` and `v` rad away from point A (center), around the Y1- and Z1-axes respectively, and then projected on a 2D map. I guess this would result in some squishy 3D->2D projection issues, but at the scales we're using it's not a problem. However I guess it might be relevant to know this to properly place points B/C in the 2D system correctly.

Here's a gif to help you understand the perspective of the image
[image]

Comment: What is a rectangle on the sphere surface? There are no parallel straight lines on a sphere surface (that are not the same line).

Comment: Are the $X_1Y_1Z_1$ coordinates Cartesian, spherical, cylindrical, or of some other kind?

Comment: @peterwhy Imagine point `A` being a person standing on a planet. His forward-direction is Z1+, right is Y1+, and his "down" (towards center of planet) is X1 (positive or negative, doesn't matter to me, I guess up as positive makes more sense, so flip it in the image). Since origo is at origo, point `A`'s position is already `(X1: radius, Y1: 0, Z1: 0)` in this "custom" system.
Let's say I want to generate a 2:1 aspect ratio map, e.g. **200m x 100m**. I traverse 100m each Y1+ and Y1-, and 50m Z1+ and Z1-, to get the four corners. Then sample the height of the surface per meter and draw 2D.

Comment: This map generation is working perfectly. However, the problem I face now is that I have no idea where to place point B on the 2D map, or even know if it's within the rectangle. I can measure the distance between A and B to know how far away it is, and would be able to draw a circle around A stating the distance of B, but I need the specific location of B relative to A in the custom system that is based on A's location/direction/rotation. Preferably in radians around Y1 and Z1, since that's what I've used to retrieve the four corners.

Comment: What is the coordinates if the person walks forward on the sphere surface for a quarter circumference or $\frac \pi2 r$? Is it $(X_1 = 0, Y_1 = 0, Z_1 = \text{radius})$? I am trying to confirm whether your new coordinates system is Cartesian or spherical. Also, since the origin is still the origin and appears to be the centre of the sphere, and the $X_1$ direction is from $A$ to the origin, the $X_1$-coordinate of $A$ has to be negative radius (not just radius).

Comment: @peterwhy You are right about that last bit. (That's what I meant about "flip it in the image" in my first comment). X1 might very well be "outwards" rather than inwards. Or not, it shouldn't matter to me as long as they're perpendicular.
As to your first question; Yes. Traversing a quarter circumference in direction Z1+ would end up at (0,0,radius), relative to that system. However, my example with "imagine a person" is bad. The person is never `A`. The person would be `B`.
`A` never moves. It's just the center of the map.

Comment: To be honest, I have probably approached this entirely wrong. I'm making a game with the ability to walk on spherical planets, and I want to open a map with my current position as center. It is important that I am able to present a map of anywhere, including the poles (I.E. the map would always represent 100m x 100m, not mercator cylindrical cutoff at poles). My method is instead to grab my "center point"(A) and traverse x radians left/right/forwards/backwards around given direction vectors (forward/right) to create my rectangle.

Comment: When my map is presented as 2D I would be able to click+drag it around, and it would generate "new" maps while dragging, placing the "new" center of the map and doing the same. It is "flawed", as I project a "3D rectangle" of a sphere onto a 2D surface, but the curvature is so small at the scales I'm using it, so it's not really noticeable. It's better to have that tiny "impurity" on all maps rather than not have the ability to drag the map across the poles.
My only problem is that I don't have a global latitude/longitude system, so I have no idea how to convert point B to point A's system..

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I start to get that the rectangle is not on the sphere surface but on the tangential plane of point $A$. All points on that rectangle has the same $X_1$-coordinate as $A$. Points on the sphere (e.g. $B$) will be converted to the new $X_1Y_1Z_1$ coordinates then have the $X_1$-coordinate dropped, i.e. an [orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection). This will represent at most a hemisphere.

Comment: @peterwhy Oh, I'm not sure that's accurate. Maybe it is. Given a 100x100 meter map with 1 pixel per meter, I sample a height-noise-generator 100x100 times to draw the terrain in the map. To get these points I first define the width and height of the surface area as radians `ra = 100/radius`, then I get to the top left point by taking `Point A`, rotating 0.5ra around `AForward`(Z1) and 0.5ra around `ARight`(Y1). When I have the top left point I sample one height value per ra/100 around Z1 (100 times), and then I rotate ra/100 once around Y1 (down), and do this row-by-row. Is this orthogonal?

Comment: Back to examples, to confirm if I understand your latest comment. Take $0.5ra=\pi/3$, and the centre point at $(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)=(R,0,0)$. Rotate this point first around the $Z_1$-axis ($(0,0,1)$) by $-0.5ra$, to get $(R/2,-R\sqrt3/2,0)$. Then rotate this point around the $Y_1$-axis ($(0,1,0)$) by $\mp0.5ra$, to get the top- and bottom-left corners $(R/4,-R\sqrt3/2,\pm R\sqrt3/4)$. Up to this point, this looks like an [equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) but with the $Y_1$-axis as the polar axis.

Comment: What to note that are: 1) in the second rotation around the $Y_1$ axis, the point is not rotating on a straight line on the sphere surface, and the length of that path is just half of $0.5ra\cdot R$. 2) The order of the two rotations, first around $Z_1$ then around $Y_1$, is *not* interchangeable, as shown by the different resultant $Y_1$ and $Z_1$ coordinates.

Comment: 3) Your next proposed rotation around $Z_1$ becomes complicated. Rotating the top- or bottom-left corner around $(0,0,1)$ by $0.5ra$ does not give a point back on the $X_1Z_1$-plane, and rotating $0.5ra$ more does not give corners symmetric about the $X_1Z_1$-plane.